# how to simplify trig functions that have different x values

Tags: derivatives

I did a question where $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{3\cos t}{-8\sin2t}$

and I checked the mark scheme and they had simplified to $-\dfrac{3}{16} \csc t$

I was confused because I though it wasn't possibly to simplify because there's the cos with one t and sin with two ts.

Do I have to use the double angle formula to get to this answer or is there another way?

Comment: $\sin(2t) = 2\sin(t)\cos(t)$, can you continue?

Comment: $$\frac{3\cos t}{-8\sin2t}=\frac{3\cos t}{-16\sin t\cos t}=-\frac{3}{16\sin t}=-\frac{3}{16}\csc t$$

Comment: thank you guys :D